# C++ casting Windows IAction

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, casting, taskscheduler

I'm working on retrieving some info from windows task scheduler.
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-actions) indicates there are several types of action. I want to deal with them separately. I tried:

```
IAction* pAction = NULL;
pActionCollection->get_Item(_variant_t(i), &pAction);
if (IExecAction* pExecAction = dynamic_cast<IExecAction*>(pAction)) { /*my work...*/ }
if (IComHandlerAction* pComHandlerAction = dynamic_cast<IComHandlerAction*>(pAction)) { /*my work...*/ }
if (IEmailAction* pEmailAction = dynamic_cast<IEmailAction*>(pAction)) { /*my work...*/ }
if (IShowMessageAction* pShowMessageAction = dynamic_cast<IShowMessageAction*>(pAction)) { /*my work...*/ }
```

But this program throws exception at the first `dynamic_cast`.

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB516365A5 (vcruntime140d.dll) in myProgram.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000130BAFEDB04.
```

The definition in `taskschd.h` shows `IExecAction` is a derived class from `IAction`.

This works well:

```
if (IExecAction* pExecAction = ((IExecAction*)pAction)) { /*my work...*/ }
```

But what if I want to do some type checking?
How could I use it properly?

Comment: you need use `QueryInterface` only for get pointer to another interface but never any c++ cast

Comment: COM interface classes are not implemented as C++ polymorphic classes. You need to use special functions for getting objects. See for example [the time trigger C++ example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/time-trigger-example--c---) for details on how to use the `QueryInterface` function to get objects.

Comment: And a note about the C-style cast: What you're doing with that is basically tell the compiler "I know what I'm doing, don't bother me". So the compiler won't bother you even if it's not correct and might lead to undefined behavior. *Never* use C-style casting.

Comment: I know, so I'm looking for something like dynamic_cast. Thanks @RbMm

Comment: you need use `IAction* pAction;
  IExecAction *pExecAction;

  HRESULT hr = pAction->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pExecAction));

  if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
  {
   // use pExecAction
   pExecAction->Release();
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for get pointer of com interface from another com interface on the same object we need use only [`QueryInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(q_)) method, which is always implemented by any interface. so code in your case need to be next:

```
    IAction* pAction;
    IExecAction* pExecAction;
    IEmailAction* pEmailAction;

    HRESULT hr;

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr = pAction->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pExecAction))))
    {
        // use pExecAction
        pExecAction->Release();
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr = pAction->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pEmailAction))))
    {
        // use pExecAction
        pEmailAction->Release();
    }
```

even if one interface inherit from another use c/c++ cast is always wrong. for example

```
    pExecAction = static_cast<IExecAction*>(pAction);
    pEmailAction = static_cast<IEmailAction*>(pAction);
```

this code is correct from c++ syntax, because both `IExecAction : IAction` and `IEmailAction : IAction` inherit from `IAction`. and this cast (if take to account layout of this 3 interfaces) give you equal binary values for `pExecAction` and `pEmailAction`. but `pExecAction`  can not have the same binary value as `pEmailAction`. must be

```
assert((void*)pEmailAction != (void*)pExecAction);
```

why ? because have `pEmailAction` and `pExecAction` have different virtual functions at the same position in *vtable*. for example on the 10-th position in the table of [`IExecAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nn-taskschd-iexecaction) must be pointer to [`get_Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-iexecaction-get_path) method. from another side on the 10-th position in the table of [`IEmailAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nn-taskschd-iemailaction) must be pointer to [`get_Server`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-iemailaction-get_server) method. if `(void*)pEmailAction == (void*)pExecAction` - they will be have the same pointers to vtable. but pointer to which function - [`get_Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-iexecaction-get_path) or [`get_Server`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-iemailaction-get_server) will be in the 10-th position ? as result pointer to this 2 interfaces can not be the same (point to the same memory). so how minimum one `static_cast` here (may be and both) give wrong result. for understand how `QueryInterface` work and why pointers to `pExecAction` and `pEmailAction` wiil be different - we need look for implementation. implementation of interfaces - this is some class, which inherit (usually) from all this interfaces and implement it like this:

```
class CAction : IExecAction, IEmailAction
{
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef( );

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface( REFIID riid, void **ppvObject)
    {
        PVOID pvObject;

        if (riid == __uuidof(IAction))
        {
            pvObject = static_cast<IExecAction*>(this);
            // or can be
            pvObject = static_cast<IEmailAction*>(this);
        }
        else if (riid == __uuidof(IExecAction))
        {
            pvObject = static_cast<IExecAction*>(this);
        }
        else if (riid == __uuidof(IEmailAction))
        {
            pvObject = static_cast<IExecAction*>(this);
        }
        else
        {
            *ppvObject = 0;
            return E_NOINTERFACE;
        }

        *ppvObject = pvObject;
        AddRef();
        return S_OK;
    }
};
```

look that `static_cast<IExecAction*>(this);` will always give another binary value compare `static_cast<IEmailAction*>(this);` - the `CAction` will be containing 2 different vtables - one for `IExecAction` and one for `IEmailAction`. they have common initial part (9 entries) but then different. and `static_cast<IExecAction*>(this);` and `static_cast<IEmailAction*>(this);` return 2 different (always) pointers to this 2 different vtables. when for `IAction*` we select return or first or second vtable pointer. both will be correct. what pointer return implementation - we can not know (the layout of actual class which implement `IExecAction`, `IEmailAction` is unknown for us)